# Error related to pushing an items to an array in state in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a button in a React app in App's state that is used in Context in another component.  It is to create a folder.

I am getting a syntax error at [...this.state.folders, newFolder].  I thought this was the way to "push" in react.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
export default class App2 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    notes: [],
    folders: [],
    newFolder: "",
    setNewFolder: e => this.setState({ newFolder: e.taget.value }),
    createFolder: e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const newFolder = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        [...this.state.folders, newFolder],
        newTodo: ""
      });
    },
    error: null
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `folders` key of the state you want to set:

```
this.setState({
  folders: [...this.state.folders, newFolder],
  newTodo: ""
});
```

Comment: Wow.  So simple and rudimentary if I just stared at it longer....Thank you!!